# Changing "Chapter" just for one chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters, naming

I am writting my thesis, using the book class.
The manuscript is in English, but the first chapter (the introduction) is in French.

I would like to have "Chapitre" instead of "Chapter" written before the chapter title "Introduction" for this chapter, but to keep "Chapter" for the next ones.

I hope my request is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary that `\renewcommand` has to be put in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapitre}
\chapter{Name of the first chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}
\chapter{This is another chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the first chapter is going to be in French one should probably also load `babel` to get the hyphenation right. In particular if one uses `\begin{otherlanguage}{french}...\end{otherlanguage}` the chapter string is automatically translated.

Comment: @moewe I think you should write your own answer for that. It is a completely new approach.

Answer (score 1):

`babel` automatically translates strings such as 'chapter' if you switch languages with the  `otherlanguage` environment. That environment will also make sure that the correct hyphenation rules are loaded. Other multilingual packages (`csquotes`, `biblatex`, ...) may also be able to make use of this.

```
\documentclass[french,british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
\chapter{French}
Bonjour
\end{otherlanguage}

\chapter{English}
Hello
\end{document}
```

[image: Chapitre 1 French Bonjour]

[image: Chapter 2 English Hello]